# Add reference in my migration error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

i create rails new demo_project using using mysql database my credentials was ok i create table my using rake db:create

```
Created database 'demo_project_development'
Created database 'demo_project_test'
```

then i generate a table

```
rails g model Product name:string description:text inventory:integer 'price:decimal{7,2}' restocked_at:datetime
```

and it was success

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.integer :inventory
      t.decimal :price, precision: 7, scale: 2
      t.datetime :restocked_at

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

after that i generate a migration

```
rails g migration AddQtySoldToProducts qty_solid:integer
```

and create this

```
class AddQtySoldToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :products, :qty_solid, :integer
  end
end
```

and after that i create another migration

```
rails g migration AddRefNumToProducts ref_num:string:index
```

and create this

```
class AddRefNumToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :products, :ref_num, :string
    add_index :products, :ref_num
  end
end
```

and the last migration

```
rails g migration AddStyleToProducts style:references
```

and create this

```
class AddStyleToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :products, :style, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

when i run `rake db:migrate` i got an error

> ## == 20170213061527 CreateProducts: migrating
>
> -- create_table(:products)    -> 0.1451s
>   == 20170213061527 CreateProducts: migrated (0.1453s) ==========================
>
> == 20170213061805 AddQtySoldToProducts: migrating =============================
>   -- add_column(:products, :qty_solid, :integer)    -> 0.3441s
>   == 20170213061805 AddQtySoldToProducts: migrated (0.3443s) ====================
>
> == 20170213061950 AddRefNumToProducts: migrating ==============================
>   -- add_column(:products, :ref_num, :string)    -> 0.0964s
>   -- add_index(:products, :ref_num)    -> 0.4156s
>   == 20170213061950 AddRefNumToProducts: migrated (0.5121s) =====================
>
> == 20170213062130 AddStyleToProducts: migrating ===============================
>   -- add_reference(:products, :style, {:foreign_key=>true}) rake aborted! StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations
>   canceled:
>
> Mysql2::Error: Cannot add foreign key constraint: ALTER TABLE
>   `products` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_326a064677` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`style_id`)   REFERENCES `styles` (`id`)
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:120:in
>   `_query'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:120:in`
>   block in query'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:119:in
>   `handle_interrupt'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:119:in`
>   query'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:218:in
>   `block in execute'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:589:in`block in log'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in
>   `instrument'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:583:in`log'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:218:in
>   `execute'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:31:in`
>   execute'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:916:in
>   `add_foreign_key'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:623:in`
>   foreign_key'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:100:in
>   `add_to'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:826:in`
>   add_reference'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:846:in
>   `block in method_missing'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:815:in`
>   block in say_with_time'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:815:in
>   `say_with_time'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:835:in`
>   method_missing'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/Desktop/demo_project/db/migrate/20170213062130_add_style_to_products.rb:3:in
>   `change'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:789:in`
>   exec_migration'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:773:in
>   `block (2 levels) in migrate'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:772:in`
>   block in migrate'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:398:in
>   `with_connection'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:771:in`
>   migrate'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:951:in
>   `migrate'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1212:in`
>   block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1282:in
>   `ddl_transaction'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1211:in`
>   execute_migration_in_transaction'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1184:in
>   `block in migrate_without_lock'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1183:in`
>   each'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1183:in
>   `migrate_without_lock'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1132:in`
>   block in migrate'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1299:in
>   `with_advisory_lock'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1132:in`
>   migrate'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1006:in
>   `up'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:984:in`
>   migrate'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:161:in
>   `migrate'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:58:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`
>   eval'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in
>   `<main>' ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Cannot add
>   foreign key constraint: ALTER TABLE`products`ADD CONSTRAINT`
>   fk_rails_326a064677`FOREIGN KEY (`style_id`)   REFERENCES`styles
>   `(`id`)
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:120:in`
>   _query'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:120:in
>   `block in query'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:119:in`
>   handle_interrupt'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:119:in
>   `query'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:218:in`
>   block in execute'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:589:in `block in log'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in`
>   instrument'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:583:in `log'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:218:in`
>   execute'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:31:in
>   `execute'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:916:in`
>   add_foreign_key'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:623:in
>   `foreign_key'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:100:in`
>   add_to'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:826:in
>   `add_reference'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:846:in`
>   block in method_missing'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:815:in
>   `block in say_with_time'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:815:in`
>   say_with_time'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:835:in
>   `method_missing'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/Desktop/demo_project/db/migrate/20170213062130_add_style_to_products.rb:3:in`
>   change'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:789:in
>   `exec_migration'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:773:in`
>   block (2 levels) in migrate'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:772:in
>   `block in migrate'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:398:in`
>   with_connection'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:771:in
>   `migrate'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:951:in`
>   migrate'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1212:in
>   `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1282:in`
>   ddl_transaction'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1211:in
>   `execute_migration_in_transaction'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1184:in`
>   block in migrate_without_lock'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1183:in
>   `each'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1183:in`
>   migrate_without_lock'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1132:in
>   `block in migrate'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1299:in`
>   with_advisory_lock'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1132:in
>   `migrate'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1006:in`
>   up'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:984:in
>   `migrate'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:161:in`
>   migrate'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:58:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in`
>   '
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in
>   `eval'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`
>   ' Mysql2::Error: Cannot add foreign key constraint
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:120:in
>   `_query'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:120:in`
>   block in query'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:119:in
>   `handle_interrupt'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:119:in`
>   query'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:218:in
>   `block in execute'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:589:in`block in log'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in
>   `instrument'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:583:in`log'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:218:in
>   `execute'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:31:in`
>   execute'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:916:in
>   `add_foreign_key'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:623:in`
>   foreign_key'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:100:in
>   `add_to'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:826:in`
>   add_reference'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:846:in
>   `block in method_missing'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:815:in`
>   block in say_with_time'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:815:in
>   `say_with_time'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:835:in`
>   method_missing'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/Desktop/demo_project/db/migrate/20170213062130_add_style_to_products.rb:3:in
>   `change'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:789:in`
>   exec_migration'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:773:in
>   `block (2 levels) in migrate'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:772:in`
>   block in migrate'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:398:in
>   `with_connection'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:771:in`
>   migrate'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:951:in
>   `migrate'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1212:in`
>   block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1282:in
>   `ddl_transaction'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1211:in`
>   execute_migration_in_transaction'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1184:in
>   `block in migrate_without_lock'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1183:in`
>   each'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1183:in
>   `migrate_without_lock'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1132:in`
>   block in migrate'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1299:in
>   `with_advisory_lock'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1132:in`
>   migrate'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1006:in
>   `up'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:984:in`
>   migrate'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:161:in
>   `migrate'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:58:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`
>   eval'
>   /Users/cdasia-tsd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in
>   `' Tasks: TOP => db:migrate (See full trace by running task with
>   --trace) TSD-Interns-MacBook-Pro:demo_project cdasia-tsd$

Comment: Is `styles` table already exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a `styles` table.

Comment: thanks bro it make sense. i just remove the foriegn key true in my reference :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, before running this migration you should create **style** table other wise you got same issue.

Please have a look below link might be it would help you -

[add_reference link1](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_reference)

[add_reference link2](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_reference)

Note: if you are writing anywhere add_reference then please make sure first this table should be present or if you want to create together all migration then order of migration should be first migration of reference table creation
after that run migration which have add_reference.